# grep specific values from .yml file

Tags: regex, shell, parsing, grep, yaml

I want to extract a specific value from `value.yml` file

```
- slug: 2352T
  en:
    term: "abc"
    def: >
      ASY
      YFH
      UUU
  pt:
    term: "cbb"
    def: >
      ATF
      TTT

- slug: HSOD5
  en:
    term: "cbs"
    def: >
     AEG
     WWW
  af:
    term: "xbb"
    def: >
     AUT
```

From this file, I want to use `grep` or anything else to extract only the following values:

```
- slug: 2352T
  en:
    term: "abc"
    def: >
      ASY
      YFH
      UUU
- slug: HSOD5
  en:
    term: "cbs"
    def: >
      AEG
      WWW
```

Can you help me with that, please?

I tried this

```
grep  "slug"  value.yml | awk -F ": " '{print $2}'
```

and I tried

```
yq r --printMode pv "slug.en.*"
```

and tried

```
yq r value.yml slug.en
```

and

```
yq r value.yml --collect slug.en.def
```

but none of them worked

Comment: `I want to use grep` grep is for lines. Use yaml aware tool to parse yaml files. That said, see `-A` option to `grep`.

Comment: Thank you @KamilCuk. Yes, am used to work with `tsb` and `tsv` which works very well with `grep`. This is my first project working with YAML and I spent a few hours thinking that `grep` will do the magic as it always does. I'll search for the YAML aware tool as you suggested.

Comment: I believe the `yq` utility (that borrows the name from `jq`) is most commonly used.

Comment: I did install it and am experimenting with it

Comment: @Sam: What is your `yq` version? Post the output of `yq --version` The Python version or the Go version?

Comment: `yq version 3.4.1` and `Python version 3.7.3` but I don't have `Go`

Comment: Each of `slug` and `en` are individual records in an object. The existing mikefaraq/yq - https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/usage/path-expressions does not allow such a path expression to filter two objects at a time

Comment: I tried `yq r value.yml en.` which works only works if I remove `-slug` from the `.yml` file and it only selects the first `en`. Is there a better way without removing anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As *KamilCuk* suggested in the comments, **use tools designed to parse yaml instead of `grep`**, but if you *have* to use `grep`, use something like `grep -A4 '^- slug:' in.yml`. This approach is **not robust** and relies on the same order of the yaml fields as you have shown in your example.

You can also use `grep -A4 --no-group-separator` if you want to remove the `--` delimiter that `grep -A` outputs in between matches.

**Example:**

Create the example input:

```
cat > in.yml <<EOF
- slug: 2352T
  en:
    term: "abc"
    def: >
      ASY
  pt:
    term: "cbb"
    def: >
      ATF.

- slug: HSOD5
  en:
    term: "cbs"
    def: >
     AEG
  af:
    term: "xbb"
    def: >
     AUT
EOF
```

Print the matching lines and the next 4 lines after each match:

```
grep -A4 '^- slug:' in.yml
```

Output:

```
- slug: 2352T
  en:
    term: "abc"
    def: >
      ASY
--
- slug: HSOD5
  en:
    term: "cbs"
    def: >
     AEG
```

Same, without the dashes between the matching blocks:

```
grep -A4 --no-group-separator '^- slug:' in.yml
```

Output:

```
- slug: 2352T
  en:
    term: "abc"
    def: >
      ASY
- slug: HSOD5
  en:
    term: "cbs"
    def: >
     AEG
```

**SEE ALSO:**

[`grep` manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html)

> `-A num`
> `--after-context=num`
> Print num lines of trailing context after matching lines.

> `--no-group-separator`
> When -A, -B or -C are in use, do not print a separator between groups of lines.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is great but unfortunately, the line after `def` is not always a single line, I made it a single line for simplicity in the minimal example. In other words, it can be more than 4 lines. I'm trying now to make it works with `yq`. Thanks again :)